# What does 'sql_query_range, sql_range_step' in sphinx.conf?

Tags: sphinx

I'm using Sphinx in our shopping site and I want to apply to realtime indexing to it.

In Sphinx documents, I don't understand `sql_query_range` and `sql_range_step`.

What does mean `sql_query_range`, `sql_range_step` in sphinx.conf?

Could you give me realtime indexing sample?

Comment: Hi, can you share the code you've tried so far? Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-query-range

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I'm reading this link.

Comment: Please accept if you've found a helpful solution.

Answer (score 2):

`sql_query_range` defines the range for the indexer. You can set the value with something like:

> `sql_query_range = SELECT MIN(id),MAX(id) FROM documents`

`sql_range_step` defines the size of your slices when you're indexing. You can set it's value with:

> `sql_range_step = 10`

Lets say we set our `sql_query_range` to find ID's 1 -> 200. With a `sql_range_step` of 10 we would end up with 20 slices. Adjusting these values can produce faster indexing times.

Source from the official docs [here](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-query-range).